# How can I insert a photo into a MySQL database with PHP using Swift iOS

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

I'm trying to insert a photo into a database using a php file with swift but I could only add the photo to a file under htdocs 'uploads' but I can't add the path to database.
Can someone tell me how to add a photo with parameters to database with swift knowing that I have used this tutorial:
http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-example/

Here is my code:

Swift

```
  //  UploadViewController.swift

    import UIKit
     class UploadViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
    {
     @IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
     @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
     @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

            //my Image upload

             myImageUploadRequest()
     }
     override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();

            print("fffffff" + defaults.stringForKey("abc")!)
               // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        }
     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

        }
     @IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

              var myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()

            myPickerController.delegate = self;

            myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

 self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
     func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {

            myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
     }
       func myImageUploadRequest()

        {
   let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/Swift/my-http-post-example.php");

            //let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.boredwear.com/utils/postImage.php");
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);

            request.HTTPMethod = "POST";


            let param = [

                "firstName"  : "Sergey",

                "lastName"    : "Kargopolov",

                "userId"    : "9"

            ]


            let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

            request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)

            if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

            request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)


            myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();



            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

                data, response, error in



                if error != nil {

                    print("error=\(error)")

                    return

                }



                // You can print out response object

                print("******* response = \(response)")



                // Print out reponse body

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")



                var err: NSError?

                do {

                var json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    self.myImageView.image = nil;

                });
            }

                catch let error as NSError {

                    print("An error occurred: \(error)")

                }



            }



            task.resume()



        }
        func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {

            var body = NSMutableData();



            if parameters != nil {

                for (key, value) in parameters! {

                    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")

                    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")

                    body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")

                }

            }

            // defaults.setValue(String("0"), forKey: "abc")

            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

            if ((defaults.stringForKey("abc")!) == ""){

                defaults.setValue(String("0"), forKey: "abc")

            }

            let filename =  (defaults.stringForKey("abc")!)+".jpg"

            defaults.setValue(String(Int((defaults.stringForKey("abc")!))!+1), forKey: "abc")

           // let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();



            //let filename = "user-profile.jpg"



            let mimetype = "image/jpg"



            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")

            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")

            body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")

            body.appendData(imageDataKey)

            body.appendString("\r\n")







            body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")



            return body

        }









        func generateBoundaryString() -> String {

            return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"

        }







    }







    extension NSMutableData {



        func appendString(string: String) {

            let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

            appendData(data!)

        }



    }
```

Here the PHP file in which I couldn't insert the photo in data

```
<?php

$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];

$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];

$userId = $_POST["userId"];



$target_dir = "uploads/";if(!file_exists($target_dir))

{

mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);

}



$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);



if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) 

{



echo json_encode([

"Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",

"Status" => "OK",

"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]

]);



} else {



echo json_encode([

"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",

"Status" => "Error",

"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]

]);



}


?>
```